# Moving (highlighting) the last row in an HTML table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help.

How can the existing jQuery code below be modified such that, at the click of a button, I would be able to move to the last row in the html table and select (highlight) it? My way of thought was that it would be possible to get the row count, then using the row count, move the selection to the last row. I guess I was wrong because its not working :(

Im jQuery friendly please.

Here is the markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<style type="text/css">

.highlight {

    background-color: rgb(255,0,0);

}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {

var rowCount = $('#data >tbody >tr').length;


    var $tbody = $("#data tbody").on('click', 'tr', function() {
            highlight($(this));
    });


    $('#goto_prev').click(function() {
        var $prev = $tbody.find('.highlight').prev();
            highlight($prev);
    });


    $('#goto_next').click(function() {
        var $next = $tbody.find('.highlight').next();
            highlight($next);
    });

    $('#goto_last').click(function() {
            highlight(rowCount);
    });

    function highlight($row) {
            if ($row.length) {
                $tbody.children().removeClass("highlight");
                $row.addClass('highlight');
                $("#rownum").val($row[0].rowIndex);
            }
    }

}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<table id="data" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>header1</th>
            <th>header2</th>
            <th>header3</th>
            <th>header4</th>
            <th>header5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
Row Number:
<br>
<input type="text" id="rownum" readonly>

<input type="button" id="goto_prev" value="prev">
<input type="button" id="goto_next" value="next">
<input type="button" id="goto_last" value="last">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: finding the `.highlight` each time jumping between rows is not efficient, especially when your table has a large number of rows (as well as your document contains a large number of elements). You should save the current row into some variable, minimize the use of query to select elements, this code seems a bit longer but it's much more efficient and it's also easy to read/maintain http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/bFru4/3/ You can use that code instead, throw away the current inefficient code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your highlight function takes a Jquery object as parameter, it won't work by sending index of row. You can solve it using this:

```
$('#goto_last').click(function() {
    highlight($("#data tr").eq(rowCount));
});
```

Comment: Or, you can use `highlight($("#data tr").last())` and get rid of `rowCount` altogether.

Comment: Yup, that's shorter in this case. Just put this to show that you can also go to nth row using eq